# Multiple types were found that match the controller named 'Home'. Where is the reference?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

There are already multiple similar questions on SO, but, they are asking how to resolve. My question is slightly different. I have read the other posts and I can see how to resolve it - (by adding the namespace to the routes)

The error I am getting is

```
The request for 'Home' has found the following matching controllers:
_01.Ui.Controllers.HomeController
ZurbMvc4.Controllers.HomeController
```

Now, the project USED to be called ZurbMvc4. I've now renamed the solution and projects, and performed a find and replace to rename ZurbMvc4 to _01.Ui

My question is, how has MVC still got a reference to ZurbMvc4 ? Performing searches (find) brings no results. I'm searching for entire project.

Opening up the solution file and the project file in notepad still finds no reference.

How do I find the reference to this old controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleted the obj and the bin folders from within Windows Explorer, a quick rebuild and its solve the problem.